# Java Files.readAllLines() is failing to close the file stream

Tags: java, scala, file-io

I am trying to use `Files.readAllLines()` to read all the lines of a file in to a Scala List. 
For a case, I need to delete the file once its read in to a List. But the problem is that the `readAllLines` method doesn't appear to be closing the file stream afterwards and because of that I am not able to delete that file after reading it.

This is how I am reading the file:
 `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(tempFile)).asScala.toList`

And after a few lines, I am doing this to delete it.
`Files.delete(Paths.get(tempFile))`

Any ideas or suggestions as to how this can be prevented?

Edit:
The exception message as requested.

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying to delete the same file ? You are using two different variables : `filePath` and `tempFile`.

Comment: Yeah its the same file. Those two lines are in two different methods and `tempFile` is the passed as argument `filePath` to the first function. So, they are the same.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem. (Scala 2.12.1) After fixing the missing `)` both lines compile and run, and the test file disappears.

Comment: I'm using 2.11.8. But surprisingly it works when I do it in the scala repl but now in the program.

Comment: How do you know that it `doesn't appear to be closing the file stream`? Any exceptions thrown?

Comment: @FredericA. I've wrapped the file deletion into a `Try` block. And I'm checking for `isSuccess` on that which is giving false. And the file still exists after the program has exited.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop Well... if you keep the exception a secret, I'm not sure we can help you ;)

Comment: @FredericA. I kind of thought that it would be obvious from the question but I guess I was wrong. Added the exception message. "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". The only other process that touches this file is the call to the `readLines` method.

Comment: Multi-threaded environment? Are you sure the side creating the temp file has closed it?

Comment: No its not multi-threaded and the temp file creation is isolated from the deletion part. And I can actually delete the file from command line after the temp file creation. So, I don't think the creation has any lock on the file. And the deleting code runs after the creation code has exited. Btw, I am creating it with `File.createTempFile`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139336/discussion-between-durga-swaroop-and-frederic-a).

Comment: Honestly having the same issue in Java 8, using Files.readAlllines then Files.delete after we process the files, and we get >The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.< message. Still trying to see why this is the case.

Comment: Honestly figured it out it was a Scanner object that was not being disposed properly.